# What will happen in Rust if create mutable variable and mutable reference and change one of them in separate thread?

Tags: concurrency, rust, ownership

I am a complete newbie in Rust and have just started getting into its ownership system (4-th chapter of the book). Compiler handles a lot of errors that may occur with values and references, but lets imagine situation below:

Let's assume there is code like this, but `change_string` opens a new thread and perform mutations there.

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("Hello");

    // perform in thread, so flow will not be synchronous
    change_string(&mut s);

    s.push_str("..........");
    println!("{}", s);
}

fn change_string(some_string: &mut String) {
    some_string.push_str(", World");
}
```

Currently I receive `Hello, World..........`, but what will happen if adding of `, World` will be in the separate thread?

Comment: What *specific* code are you asking about? rodrigo's answer pretty thoroughly explains why this is unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: There is no answer to this question because 1) The compiler won't let you do that (because `&mut` cant be sent to a different thread) in order to prevent the second reason 2) the result would be undefined. If there are no atomics that define the order of operations to some degree, all sorts of things could happen. For example, the `change_string`-thread might not get scheduled by the OS at all and you get `Hello......`, then the second thread runs, the string has already been deallocated, hilarity ensues...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust will not let you do unsafe things (without using the `unsafe` keyword), that includes anything related with threads. Why not just try and see how it fails to compile?

```
fn change_string(some_string: &mut String) {
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
            some_string.push_str(", World");
    });
}
```

It produces this error:

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `some_string`
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
13 | fn change_string_1(some_string: &mut String) {
   |                                 ----------- help: add explicit lifetime `'static` to the type of `some_string`: `&'static mut std::string::String`
14 |     std::thread::spawn(move || {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'static` required
```

This means that you cannot pass a reference with a non-static lifetime to a thread, because the thread could live longer than such reference, and that would be unsafe.

You were probably thinking about issues with data races, but those are actually not the problem. The real problem is that your `String` may live as long as the thread. Actually, if you use scoped threads, from the `crossbeam` crate, it will just work:

```
fn change_string(some_string: &mut String) {
    crossbeam::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|_| {
            some_string.push_str(", World");
        });
    }).unwrap();
}
```

Now it works because the `crossbeam::scope()` call will not return until all the threads spawned inside are completed. And thus the lifetime of your `String` is always strictly longer than the thread and everything just works.

But what about data races? There are none, because `&mut` references in Rust are *unique*. This means that you cannot have two of them pointing to the same object, so it doesn't matter from what thread you are changing your object (as long as your object implements `Sync` but most do), you are doing it from just one, and there are no races.

If you try to create two threads to modify the object, even with `crossbeam`:

```
fn change_string(some_string: &mut String) {
    crossbeam::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|_| {
            some_string.push_str(", World");
        });
        s.spawn(|_| {
            some_string.push_str(", World");
        });
    }).unwrap();
}
```

You get this error message:

```
error[E0524]: two closures require unique access to `some_string` at the same time
```

Remember that `&mut` means unique access in addition to ability to mutate.

And if you try to move the reference into the closures instead of borrowing it:

```
fn change_string(some_string: &mut String) {
    crossbeam::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(move |_| {
            some_string.push_str(", World");
        });
        s.spawn(move |_| {
            some_string.push_str(", World");
        });
    }).unwrap();
}
```

You get this one in the second closure:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `some_string`
```

because the reference was already moved into the first one and cannot be used again.

Of course you can spawn a thread from the thread and that will work:

```
fn change_string(some_string: &mut String) {
    crossbeam::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|s| {
            some_string.push_str(", World");
            s.spawn(|_| {
                some_string.push_str(", World");
            });
        });
    }).unwrap();
}
```

But notice how it is still totally race free, because once the second thread is created the first one loses access to the unique mutable reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I've tried with thread (like in your first example), and was not sure if there are some ways to get around it

Comment: @BLukash: Other than the crossbeam crate, you can use a `Mutex`. Unlike other languages, Mutexes in Rust cannot be misused.